# Check strings format in SQL - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around 50 different strings formats (e.g. 00-000-000, 123-456-789-123AAA, CHE-123.456.789IVA ... etc.). Those are TAX registration number formats for different country. I need to check for each company tax registration number if it's following its country format or not. I need to check two levels of conformance.
1. The number of digits for for string and sub-strings (e.g. two digits before first dash in 11-111-11 and so on)
2. The type of digits for each string (number of character).

Is that possible in SQL? I tried some functions but all about the size and the length of the string, not the format.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you please explain it more with a sample?

Comment: You could try something like [regexp_like](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) - but it's not very fast as far as I know.

Comment: The solution that I am looking for is exactly like what @Robert Merkwürdigeliebe suggested below except that I was looking for more generic that can be applied to all formats in stead of writing query for each country format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to use regular expressions. But you'll have to define those for all country formats. This one is for an social security number:
3 numbers, a dash, 2 numbers, dash, 4 numbers.

```
create table re (country varchar2(10),reg varchar2(100));

insert into re values ('us','^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$');

select 
   case when regexp_like('987-65-4321' ,reg) 
      then 'Match Found' 
      else 'No Match Found' 
   end as output 
from re
where country = 'us';

Match Found
```